# Find the number of certifications held by people, grouped by planet.

Tags: sql

This is part of my SQL homework and I can't wrap my head around it.  It should have two colums, name and CertCount.  Where name = planet name.  and CertCount = total number of certificates all people with that homeworld have.

These are the tables i'm working with: http://pastebin.com/kNRNGQFv

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT bsg_people.homeworld, (SUM(cid) 
 AS 'CertCount'
   FROM bsg_people 
   INNER JOIN bsg_cert_people ON id=cid)
GROUP BY bsg_people.homeworld;
```

I just can't seem to figure this out because there is no value to count the number of certificates each person has.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: The link you gave is not working.  Try creating tables in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and share that. Also mention the db/version you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple `count(*)`, without the subquery and **join to the right column** - your pastebin shows that the foreign key to person is on `pid` (not `cid`):

```
CONSTRAINT `bsg_cert_people_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `bsg_people` (`id`)
```

Also, join to the planets tables to get the name of the planet in your output.

Try this:

```
select bsg_planets.name homeworld, count(*) CertCount
from bsg_planets
join bsg_people on bsg_planets.id = bsg_people.homeworld
join bsg_cert_people on id = pid
group by bsg_planets.name
```

Also, you had a syntax error: You quoted the alias "CertCount" like this: `'CertCount'`, but that's a string literal. You need an alias, without quotes, like this `CertCount`.

Comment: I looked at the pastebin and I also suspect the join should be on `bsg_cert_people.pid` rather than `cid`.

Comment: @shawnt00 well spotted. I've included your bug find in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but its telling me I selected the wrong columns.  Figured I need to join bsg_planets to get the name from that table, so I did  `JOIN bsg_planets where homeworld = id` but it tells me `Column 'id' in on clause is ambiguous`

Comment: Ambiguous means it doesn't know whether you mean the `id` from `bsg_people` or `bsg_cert_people`. You need to tell it which one. If you search online on that error what do you find?

Comment: Ah, I see what I did wrong.  It needed to be `JOIN bsg_planets on bsg_planets.id = bsg_people.homeworld` and then `GROUP BY bsg_planets.name`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than answer your question directly (which would sort of defeat the purpose of the homework which is for you to learn), I'll try to point you in the right direction :)

How are you joining bsg_cert_people onto bsg_people?  Look at which fields are referring to people and which are referring to certifications, and make sure that you're using them the correct way.  While not essential in this case, using table aliases (instead of just "id=cid") and neatening up the query a bit can really help with getting a better mental picture of what the joins and such are doing.